# Can't build the NativeScript custom module with TypeScript

Tags: android, ios, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I build NativeScript project with TypeScript

In my module as this code,

but I get the error of "TS2306: file is not a module.",

Is any problem of setup?

models/version/version-common.ts

```
export function version() {

}
```

models/version/version.d.ts

```
declare module "models/version" {
    export function getVersion();

    export class version {

    }
}
```

models/version/version.ios.ts

```
import common = require("./version");

global.moduleMerge(common, exports);
export function getVersion() {
    console.log("go iOS");
}
```

models/version/version.android.ts

```
import common = require("./version");

global.moduleMerge(common, exports);
export function getVersion() {
    console.log("go android");
}
```

This is my folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see the problem is with this import:

```
import common = require("./version");
```

In order to import your `common` you should change it in both ios and android files to:

```
import common = require("./version-common");
```